# Compiler treatment of struct function pointers

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Recently, I've been seeing an interesting way to implement an analogue of explicit namespacing in C. This is accomplished by using a `struct` to store `const` function pointers, like this:

foo.h:

```
extern const struct foo_namespace {
    void (* const bar)(int a, int b);
    int (* const baz)();
    char *(* const qux)(const char *str);
} Foo;
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

const struct foo_namespace Foo = {
    .bar = /* some function */,
    .baz = ... ,
    .qux = ...
};
```

This allows one to call the functions as `Foo.bar()`, similar to C++'s `Foo::bar()`. I've been thinking about this technique and would like to use it, but thought of some issues.

1. Is the compiler likely to inline the entire struct such that calls through the function pointers are replaced by the functions themselves? It seems unlikely since `const` does not actually declare a compile-time constant. This would also make it impossible to have any namespaced functions inlined.
2. What executable section is this likely to be stored in? It seems possible that this could be a security problem if it's possible to clobber the struct
   and install different function pointers.

Comment: This is quite different from namespaces. It is a runtime matter, while namespaces are compile time. The address different issues.

Comment: @Olaf Which is why I referred to it as an analogue, and why I'm interested in the ability of the compiler to perform optimizations on it.

Comment: An analogue implies similar semantics to address a similar problem. Which is not what the two features do. Function pointer in a `struct` is more an approach of OOP in C than emulating namespaces. For namespaces, just use a prefix or a macro to generate names from a module name plus function name.

Comment: While the "OOP-in-C" approach mentioned by @Olaf is commonly used (X11/Xt is a good example) your approach is definitely something that might cause one or the other risen eyebrow in production code. After all, you got a nearly unlimited supply of name prefixes and underscores to maintain namespaces.

Comment: Making the pointers inside the struct `const` is redundant if you have made the whole struct `const`

Answer (score 1):

1) you don't care, with branch prediction the overhead is in the nanoseconds.

2) consts are usually copied to ram for faster access. But the risk seems the same as using symbols to resolve functions.

Comment: Any idea if the compiler can inline functions called this way?

Comment: It can, the question is if it will. Google about *inline const function pointers*

Comment: Very unlikely. You are (especially in plain C) not using a very commonly used construct. A C++ compiler might be more ambitious in that respect.